# NSData set tag value

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdata

My question is, Why is there no tag value for NSData? I have looked for help but did not find any constructive one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by tag value? Can you give an example of something that does have tag value? Or what it means.

Comment: you are joined SOF around 2 years but you don't know what is diff b/w widget and variable

Comment: @iDev I was unaware of that, thanks for the comment/enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSData is object it is not a any of widgets. widget only have tag variable

Widget mean button,label,textview.,etc.,

Comment: In other words, *UIView* has the *tag* property. *NSObject* does not have. *NSData* is the extension of *NSObject*.